# Discrete signals notation underlined value

Tags: discrete-signals

In a book i have there's an exercise that want to find the output of a system for a given  signal

system: $ 2y(n)=2x(n)+x(n+1)+x(n-1) $

input : $ Χ=[\underline1, -1, 2, 0, -2, 0, 1 ]$

$Χ1=Χ[0] $

What represent's the underlined value?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: which book are you referring to? (because I've never seen this notation)

Comment: it's an internal book from my uni.

Comment: Very interesting concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arrow or an underline is used to indicate the value at $n=0$. Example,

$$y(n) = \begin{array}{ccccc}[&9 &8 &\underline7 &6 &5 &]\end{array}$$ means that,
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}&y(-2) = 9, &y(-1) =8, &y(0)=7, &y(1) = 6 &\mathrm{and} &y(2) =5\end{array}$$

In your case, it says that $$\begin{array}{ccccc}&X(0) = 1, &X(1) =-1, &X(2)=2, &\ldots\end{array}$$

**Note:** No underline or arrow is equivalent to underlining the first value.